# How do I specify error of Y-variable when fitting with lmfit?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, lmfit

I'm almost new to Python and I'm trying to fit data from college using lmfit. The Y variable has a variable error of 3%. How do I add that error to the fitting process? I am changing from scipy's curve fit and in scipy it was really easy to do so, just creating an array with the error values and specifying the error when fitting by adding the text "sigma = [yourarray]"
This is my current code:

```
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
w1, V1, phi1, scal1 = np.loadtxt("./FiltroPasaBajo_1.txt", delimiter = "\t", unpack = True)

t = w1
eV= V1*0.03 + 0.01

def funcion(parametros, x, y):
    R = parametros['R'].value
    C = parametros['C'].value

    modelo = 4/((1+(x**2)*(R**2)*(C**2))**1/2)
    return modelo - y
parametros = Parameters()
parametros.add('R', value = 1000, min= 900, max = 1100)
parametros.add('C', value = 1E-6, min = 1E-7, max = 1E-5)

fit = Minimizer(funcion, parametros, fcn_args=(t,V1))
resultado = fit.minimize()


final = V1 + resultado.residual
report_fit(resultado)

try:
    plt.plot(t, V1, 'k+')
    plt.plot(t, final, 'r')
    plt.show()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

V1 are the values I measured, and eV would be the array of errors. t is the x coordinate.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minimize()` function minimizes an array in the least-square sense, adjusting the variable parameters in order to minimize `(resid**2).sum()`  for the `resid` array returned by your objective function.  It really does not know anything about the uncertainties in your data or even about your data.  To use the uncertainties in your fit, you need to pass in your array `eV` just as you pass in `t` and `V1` and then use that in your calculation of the array to be minimized.

One typically wants to minimize `Sum[  (data-model)^2/epsilon^2 ]`, where `epsilon` is the uncertainty in the data (your `eV`), so the residual array should be altered from `data-model` to `(data-model)/epsilon`.    For your fit, you would want

```
def funcion(parametros, x, y, eps):
    R = parametros['R'].value
    C = parametros['C'].value

    modelo = 4/((1+(x**2)*(R**2)*(C**2))**1/2)
    return (modelo - y)/eps
```

and then use this with

```
fit = Minimizer(funcion, parametros, fcn_args=(t, V1, eV))
resultado = fit.minimize()
...
```

If you use the `lmfit.Model` interface (designed for curve-fitting), then you could pass in `weights` array that multiplies `data -model`, and so would be `1.0 / eV` to represent weighting for uncertainties (as above with `minimize`).  Using the `lmfit.Model` interface and providing uncertainties would then look like this:

```
from lmfit import Model
# model function, to model the data
def func(t, r, c):
    return 4/((1+(t**2)*(r**2)*(c**2))**1/2)

model  = Model(func)
parametros = model.make_params(r=1000, c=1.e-6)

parametros['r'].set(min=900, max=1100)
parametros['c'].set(min=1.e-7, max=1.e-5)

resultado = model.fit(V1, parametros, t=t, weights=1.0/eV)

print(resultado.fit_report())

plt.errorbar(t, V1, eV, 'k+', label='data')
plt.plot(t, resultado.best_fit, 'r', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

hope that helps....

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! Also, do you know any package that can fit functions and assign the error in the X and Y variables and not only the Y variable?

Comment: `scipy.optimize.ODR` can use uncertainties in both `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot provide sigma in fit.minimize() directly.

However I see that fit.minimize() uses scipy's leastsq method (by default) which is the same method used by scipy's curve_fit.

If you look into [scipy's curve_fit source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L504-L792), it does following with the sigma (for 1-d case).

```
 transform = 1.0 / sigma
 jac = _wrap_jac(jac, xdata, transform)
 res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
```

Since fit.minimize() allows you to pass kwargs (Dfun) for leastsq, you can pass the jac the way it is done in scipy curve_fit.

Comment: Thank you for your early reply! I pasted your code into mine, but I get a few errors. First of all, I get a "module 'scipy.optimize' has no attribute '_wrap_jac'" error.
Then, I know it's a stupid question but what is kwargs and how do I pass it from minimize? So the Idea is to fit the function with minimize and no sigma and then fit it again with leastsq? Also jac is the variable which specifies the "sigma"? I'm so lost

Comment: Can u post your data somewhere so I can work on it and show how it can be done.

Comment: ok, here it is
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cbGJiBdoQdH6nHlpElDONxapqk4AJjsa?usp=sharing

Comment: also, in the same folder is my old program "PASA BAJO.py" which uses scipy.optimize, and it fits quite well but it has the problem that the errors of the variable R and C are infinite. That's why I'm trying to do a new program using lmfit with hopes the ridiculously high errors dissapear

Comment: both of them use the same algorithm (leastsq), so I wouldnt say lmfit will be better.

Comment: by adding bounds to the parametres in curvefit method I was able to get reasonable error estimates. poptr, pcovr = curve_fit(Vrc, t, V1**2, p0 = [1000, 1E-6], bounds = ([500,0.5E-6], [2000,5E-6]), sigma = eV**2, absolute_sigma = True) lead to R:   (991.79011233 +- 28.69332400) C:   (0.00000099 +- 0.00000003), which makes more sense.